# Regex matching street type if street name starts with it

Tags: regex

I am having issues with street names that start with words like stars, avenue, etc.. because they contain st, and ave in the beginning. I know it has something to do with the (?<=\s) however I cannot seem to get the regex adjusted right to correct this issue.

[Test Link](https://regex101.com/r/h3LYzN/10)

```
(\d+).*?((?:[a-z0-9].*(?:[a-z]|[^\S\r\n])+)).*?((?<=\s)(?:court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|lane|ln|rd|blvd|cir|trl|trai|crossing|xing|pl|place|ave|cv|cove|trce|trace|mnr|way|loop|bnd|bend|lndg|landing|path|pkwy|parkway|pass|rdg|ridge|vw)).*?((?:UNT|\#)[^\S\r\n]?\w|\w.*)?$|(\d+).*?((?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]|[^\S\r\n])+))$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `\b` (word boundary) after the special word alternative list (stripped version first):

```
...(?:court|ct|street|st|...|vw)\b...
                                ^^
```

And the whole regex:

```
(\d+).*?((?:[a-z0-9].*(?:[a-z]|[^\S\r\n])+)).*?((?<=\s)(?:court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|lane|ln|rd|blvd|cir|trl|trai|crossing|xing|pl|place|ave|cv|cove|trce|trace|mnr|way|loop|bnd|bend|lndg|landing|path|pkwy|parkway|pass|rdg|ridge|vw)\b).*?((?:UNT|\#)[^\S\r\n]?\w|\w.*)?$|(\d+).*?((?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]|[^\S\r\n])+))$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/h3LYzN/11

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I understand your needs right, you want to validate a street address, and if valid, match groups on building #, street name, street type, and optional unit #. for locking on the street type, you can surround it with the boundary condition '\b'.

So this should be a much more efficient version of the query you want (avoiding nested * in *)

```
^([0-9]+)\ (.*?)\ \b(court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|lane|ln|rd|blvd|cir|trl|trai|crossing|xing|pl|place|ave|cv|cove|trce|trace|mnr|way|loop|bnd|bend|lndg|landing|path|pkwy|parkway|pass|rdg|ridge|vw)\b.*?\b([0-9]+)?$
```